# Wingdings font in FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to use font Wingdings  in my app, 
it is working well in IE, but in FF and Chrome instead of chars I see a latter.
How to use this font in FF in correct way ?

```
.changehistorybtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: hsl(215, 47%, 57%);
  font-family: Wingdings 3;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
font-family: "Wingdings 3";
```

Comment: Note that this won't work on anything but Windows though, as Wingdings is not a standard font.

Comment: Hi thanks.  now it is workin in Chrome and IE but not in FF 10. Could you please give me link to  info about this difference ?

Comment: IF you set a fallback font family, does that load? So something like font-family:"Wingdings 3", Verdana;

Comment: JUST Z latters IN FF, this link how it should be (and working in Chrome and IE), http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/715645-224201233014PM.

Comment: I don't know. If you just need to make a triangle, have you looked into playing around with borders? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: Sorry to revive an old thread but it seems that as of the latest version of chrome this no longer works.